# Detect button up/down status in Vim / Vimscript

Tags: vim

Is there a way to detect if a button is being held down, e.g. ctrl.  I searched through a few promising help topics and couldn't find an answer.

Reason is, once arriving within a VimScript function, I'd like to stay within a particular loop while ctrl is being held down, and exit once it's released.

Comment: It's impossible AFAIK: the Ctrl key is not recognized by Vim as an actual key so it can't say if it's pressed or not. What about explaining what you are after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying the key state of individual (modifier) keys would only work in GVIM, not in the terminal (because that only sends full complete keystrokes). As Vim favors consistency over GUI-only features (cp. `:help design-not`), that isn't possible, and won't be.

If you're really desperate for that feature, you could implement this in native code, loaded into Vim via a DLL / shared library and `libcall()`. But I'd recommend to rather re-think your approach; there's certainly a different way.

Comment: I'm open to an alternative.  My hope was to make something like Alt-Tab or Ctrl-Tab functionality to switch between buffers or tabs [link](http://vimrcfu.com/snippet/103).  Pressed once and released switches to the MRU buffer/tab, while pressed once with Ctrl held down migrates further down the MRU history.  I tried many ways to navigate between buffers and tab, both native and plugin, but this behavior on Windows is ubiquitous and useful, and one I'm accustomed to.  Maybe after a ctrl-tab into the function, stay in a loop, until next keypress isn't Tab?  What to use to read the next key?

Comment: sorry didn't notice my edits didn't save (5 min window).  i already do have [a script to use ctrl-tab](http://vimrcfu.com/snippet/103), but I'd like to replicate the behavior to go deeper into the MRU history.  It's hard to overload the ctrl-tab behavior (both immediate switch to MRU, and also going deeper) without noting the key press status.  I think I do have an alternative, to stay in a loop until the next keypress isn't a tab.  While only tab is being pressed, go deeper in the MRU list.  What would be the best way to read the next keypress?

Comment: Answering my own question, re: getting next keypress, getchar() is probably what I'm after.

Comment: Right, and with `getcharmod()` you can even check that Ctrl is still pressed.